# How to use validate check fb id at the time of signup?

Tags: javascript, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am making an API in es6. there in signup routes, i need to check the FB id of the user that whether FB id is wrong or not. how to do this in javascript?

Comment: The question is a little vague and too general. Can you provide more information?

Comment: in my application, there is a signup page .. user will give some information in that like name, age and FB id .. I need to check that FB id is correct or not.